# Install propel using composer

Tags: php, propel, composer-php

I am trying to use propel with composer but I'm getting errors.

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel" : "*"
    }
}
```

and the error is:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package propel/propel * could not be found.
```

Does anyone knows what am I missing? I'm googling it but I don't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to use propel 1.x or propel 2?

Try this for propel1:

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel1": "1.6.*"
    }
}
```

For propel 2, I think this can work:

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was correct for 2012, but that was 11 years ago.  We should be using Propel at version 2, or even version 3 if you are brave.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
    }
}
```

This is the one we actually use.